# AWS Backup customize Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup

I'm using AWS Backup service to generate daily, weekly etc.. snapshots of EBS volumes. Needless to say, I have 100s of snapshots being generated which I'm using vaults to organize. Is there a way to customize the Name field? I wanted to id the NAME fields with Daily or Weekly. Apparently I can use tags but with so many daily snapshots, it would be really nice to customize the NAME field and add Daily or Weekly to make it easier to view. I could not find much in documentation about this on AWS. Any help or suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: is the name not just the value of the Name tag?  For many AWS resources it is.  Test and see whether that gives you the result you want.

Comment: Even if the snapshot name is not just the Name tag, you can make any tag visible in the AWS console - use the 'show column' option on the snapshot tag.